# BigQuery: How to autoreload table with new storage JSON files?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have just created one BigQuery table by linking available JSON files in Google Cloud Storage. But I do not see any option to auto-reload table rows with new files added in Google Cloud Storage folder or bucket.

Currently, I have to go to BigQuery console and then delete & recreate the same table to load new files. But this solution is not scalable for us because we run a cron job on BigQuery API. How to auto-reload data in BigQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define External Table on top of Files in Google Cloud Storage  - you can use wildcard for Source Location, so your table will represent all files that match

Then, when you query such table - you can use _file_name field which will "tell" you which file given row came from

```
SELECT  
  _file_name AS file,
  *
FROM `yourTable`
```

This way - whenever you add new file in GCS - you will get it in table "automatically"

Comment: Nice solution Mikhail. OP should bear in mind that using federated sources will incur a performance hit rather than materialising to native tables. Another option would be to write a little Cloud Function to trigger on new files arriving in the bucket. The cloud function can then kick off a BQ load job to a native table, or a Dataflow pipeline.

Comment: you are right, meantime as OP mentioned "linking" I assumed he already is using federated table but just didn't know how to handle new tables. but this can be wrong assumption from my side. And yes, cloud function "linked" to bucket, etc. is the simple way to go if new files needs to be actually loaded - totally agree :o)

Comment: That's exactly my assumption too. Just wanted to point out to OP that there are other (neater!?) options available ;-)

Comment: How to kick off a BQ load job to a native table? Delete table and recreate one?

Comment: Thanks for the extra knowledge and correct answer, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With Google Cloud Functions you can automate BigQuery each time you receive a new file:

- Create a new function at https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/add
- Point "bucket" to the one receiving files.

Codewise, import BigQuery inside `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^0.9.6"
  } 
}
```

And on `index.js` you can act on the new file in any appropriate way:

```
var bigQuery = BigQuery({ projectId: 'your-project-id' });

exports.processFile = (event, callback) => {
  console.log('Processing: ' + JSON.stringify(event.data));
  query(event.data);
  callback();
};

var BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

function query(data) {
    const filename = data.name.split('/').pop();
    const full_filename = `gs://${data.bucket}/${data.name}`

    // if you want to run a query:
    query = '...'
    bigQuery.query({
        query: query,
        useLegacySql: false
    });
};
```