# Easiest way to bulk load 100 sql csv table dumps to bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi what would be the easiest and fastest way to bulk load 100 csv sql table dumps to new tables in bigquery.

Br,
Noomster

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a Cloud Function that observes a bucket and when you upload a file to the bucket it will be imported into BigQuery, see a code example here:

[BigQuery: How to autoreload table with new storage JSON files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656243/bigquery-how-to-autoreload-table-with-new-storage-json-files/50455805#50455805)